# Sinatra Framework, handsontable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, handsontable

Does anyone know if it's possible to use the handsontable add on with a Sinatra framework? The Gem on rubygems.org mentions Rails only so I wasn't sure if the add on was only made for/intended for Rails.

Comment: It requires the asset-pipeline it seems. The gem is outdated anyways, you're better off just adding the js/css files by hand.

Comment: Could you provide a quick example, berry newb here. :) Do you mean in html/haml to link the src for js and css? Should I actually download source and copy to my working directory and point to them in there or just via weblink?

Comment: https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/tree/master/dist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recomend the same as [@iceman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308731). Just use the js and css direct.

Most time I sort the files in two folders on for js and css, you endup with something like:

```
yourappolder
   -public
     -js
        -handsontable.full.js
     -css
        -handsontable.full.css
```

That this folder is named public is convention. From the [doc](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html):

A string specifying the directory where static files should be served from. By default, this is assumed to be a directory named “public” within the root directory (see the :root setting). You can set the public directory explicitly with:

```
set :public_folder, '/var/www'
set :public_folder, Proc.new { File.join(root, "static") }
```

These files can now directly included in your layout file

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title My title
    %link(rel="stylesheet" href="/css/handsontable.full.css")
    %script{:type => "text/javascript", :src => "/js/handsontable.full.js"}
  %body
    = yield
```

Or you can build a view, where you require you files. And render these view in you layout. (It add a bit more structure)

To answer your question:

> Should I actually download source and copy to my working directory and point to them in there or just via weblink?

Have a copy of the used files, just for the case. And use the weblink, because most time it's faster for your user. (They have cdn's)

If you build a intranet site or want host the css/js yourself, have a look at [sinatra-assetpack](http://ricostacruz.com/sinatra-assetpack/), this can combine and minify your css/js for a faster download.

**Update:**
I've been told that handsontable work no without jquery so I updated my answer. If you use a old version of handsontable you should probably load the jquery javascript file (and before the handsontable js file).

Comment: Oh... so doing this then... should that really work for any framework still or only Rails? I figure it's just js and css so should really work with anything that supports the styles and js. just wanted to be clear though.

Comment: "should that really work for any framework still or only Rails" not sure what you mean with 'that', but if you mean handsontable, definitely. This type of gems for rails are just bloated helper to made your life a bit easier.

Comment: Sorry by 'that' I meant the solution of linking to /css/jquery.handsontable.full and the /js/jquery/min.js, /js/jquery/handsontable.js just by hand. Makes sense. I could swear that's what I've tried but I didn't see any table on my quick site. I'll have to post my code to show what I tried (something similar to the solution you provided). I'll get back on here in a bit with my code.

Comment: Note, Handsontable has phased out using jquery, it now uses native DOM only. Thus it now requires two files [not three]. Eg handsontable.full.js & handsontable.full.css